# How to close custom made prompt box in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

I'm trying to make a custom prompt box in javascript. However, I just can't figure out how to close it again. The cancel button does work (the prompt box disappears), but when you click on the ok button, the box doesn't disappear.

Since I based my code on the code on this page: https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Custom-Prompt-Box-Programming-Tutorial

But now I see that if I copy the example on that page, the OK button doesn't work either. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

This is the example on the site I linked to, which doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
#dialogoverlay{
    display: none;
    opacity: .8;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
#dialogbox{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background: #000;
    border-radius:7px; 
    width:550px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#dialogbox > div{ background:#FFF; margin:8px; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxhead{ background: #666; font-size:19px; padding:10px; color:#CCC; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxbody{ background:#333; padding:20px; color:#FFF; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxfoot{ background: #666; padding:10px; text-align:right; }
</style>
<script>

function changeText(val){
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = val;
}
function doStuff(val){
    document.body.style.background = val;
}
function CustomAlert(){
    this.render = function(dialog){
        var winW = window.innerWidth;
        var winH = window.innerHeight;
        var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
        var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
        dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
        dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
        dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
        dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
        dialogbox.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "Acknowledge This Message";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
        document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Alert.ok()">OK</button>';
    }
    this.ok = function(){
        document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    }
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
function CustomConfirm(){
    this.render = function(dialog,op,id){
        var winW = window.innerWidth;
        var winH = window.innerHeight;
        var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
        var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
        dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
        dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
        dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
        dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
        dialogbox.style.display = "block";

        document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "Confirm that action";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
        document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Confirm.yes(\''+op+'\',\''+id+'\')">Yes</button> <button onclick="Confirm.no()">No</button>';
    }
    this.no = function(){
        document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    }
    this.yes = function(op,id){
        if(op == "delete_post"){
            deletePost(id);
        }
        document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    }
}
var Confirm = new CustomConfirm();
function CustomPrompt(){
    this.render = function(dialog,func){
        var winW = window.innerWidth;
        var winH = window.innerHeight;
        var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
        var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
        dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
        dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
        dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
        dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
        dialogbox.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "A value is required";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
        document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML += '<br><input id="prompt_value1">';
        document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Prompt.ok(\''+func+'\')">OK</button> <button onclick="Prompt.cancel()">Cancel</button>';
    }
    this.cancel = function(){
        document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    }
    this.ok = function(func){
        var prompt_value1 = document.getElementById('prompt_value1').value;
        window[func](prompt_value1);
        document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    }
}
var Prompt = new CustomPrompt();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
<div id="dialogbox">
  <div>
    <div id="dialogboxhead"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxbody"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxfoot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<h1>My web document content ...</h1>
<h2>My web document content ...</h2>
<button onclick="alert('You look very pretty today.')">Default Alert</button>
<button onclick="Alert.render('You look very pretty today.')">Custom Alert</button>
<button onclick="Prompt.render('And you also smell very nice.')">Custom Alert 2</button>
<h3>My web document content ...</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I now added the code example which is based on the site.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the second parameter for the `ok` button click, which allows you to invoke a function once you click ok:

```
<button onclick="Prompt.render('And you also smell very nice.', 'doStuff')">Custom Alert 2</button>
```

This will invoke `doStuff` with the value from the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

There is one possibility check with the id's used for elements in you the code provided if at all there are duplicate id the javaScript will not work properly.

This statement in the code,

```
document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
```

Is making use of element with id 'dialogbox' so if at all there is another element in your page having same id. your code will not work properly. More help can be provided if there is code with problem is shared.

Comment: The code as displayed on the site I linked to gives the same error. So I guess there has to be an error in there.